# Is it possible to save the state of a style, on a rendered component within React Native?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I am currently building out an application with React Native. The purpose of the application is for the user to create packlists and then be able to checkoff the items they have already "packed".

As it stands right now, I have the style of the list dynamically rendering with a ternary expression. When the user checks off the box, the box then changes color and strikes a line through the item.

The problem is, when I use either the stack/tab/drawer navigator, the page rerenders and anything that has been checked off, goes back to its original state. I wasn't sure if there was a way to "hold" the state of the style within the component.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure but you should try using the useNavigation hook.

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
```

You then can try something like that:

```
const navigation = useNavigation()
navigation.addListener('focus', function () {
    //Load States
});

navigation.addListener('blur', function () {
    //Save states
});
```

Comment: You then could use AsyncStorage for saving the states locally, I know its not a nice way to load them each time the user focuses the page but its the only one i can think of so far

Comment: better than I can think of! I will give it a try, thanks!